# how to click a button in c# forms from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple buttons in a form like "Refresh","Close","Save","Delete".
I want function keys like F1,F2,F3 etc. to assign for these buttons so that user presses on these assigned function keys, these buttons to be clicked.
I know how to go to keydown event of the form and do these simply.

As i have similar other forms and buttons, so i need to eliminate the redundancy and to move the relevant code into a class.

How can i achieve this..?..

When i asked this, i got answer from Kai Thoma, which was exactly i was looking.

the answer is :-

step 1 : create a class as below

```
public static class RefreshHandler
{
    public static void HookRefreshButton(Form form, Button btnDelete, Button btnRefresh, Button btnOk)
    {
        form.KeyPreview = true;
        form.KeyDown += (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F4) btnDelete.PerformClick();
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F5) btnRefresh.PerformClick();
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F10) btnOk.PerformClick();
        };
    }
}
```

step 2: invoke it from the forms constructor or load as below :-

```
private void frmForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {RefreshHandler.HookRefreshButton(this, btnDelete, btnRefresh, btnOk);}
```

Thats it. Its working perfect. Thanks alot to Kai.

But, i guess this can be implemented using interface in a better way. If so, please guide me how to do that using interfaces..?.

Thanks

Comment: Oh c'mon! This is probably the mostly asked question here on Stack Overflow. How about doing some own searching? Just look at the "Related" link list on the right of this page.

Comment: What do you want to do? Moving the shortcut assignment code to a separate file to reuse it on other forms and avoid code redundance? Or just having the possibillity to invoke refresh on the forms from 'outside' via a public method?

Comment: @Kai Thoma, just want to moving the shortcut assgnment code to a separate file to reuse it on other forms and avoid code redundance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 public class MyClassEvent
 {
     public static void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        Button mybotton = sender as Button;
         Form myform = mybotton.Parent as Form; //If button is directly onform     
     }

 }
```

In your form:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        button1.Click += MyClassEvent.OnClick;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if u can give me bit more clarification, appreciated. My case is, from the separate class, i need to be able to call that click event or the method written in the click event which is private which is written in that form itself. i don't want that click event as public in the class.

Comment: Normally, a click event handler invokes a method like `protected void Refresh()`. The most natural way for solving your problem was to make this method public. If you don't want to have it public for any reason you can use reflection to invoke it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if u can give me bit more clarification, appreciated. my code snippet in the form is as be low :-     private void frmInsurance_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F5)
            {
                btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);
            }
        } ............. i want this F5 checking and process from a separate class.

Comment: @Kai thoma. if i make those methods public, since i have lots of forms, that is not a good practise na... and i dont prefer reflection too. any other suggestions pls...

Comment: Try this: `public static class RefreshHandler
 {
  public static void HookRefreshButton( Form form, Button button )
  {
   form.KeyPreview = true;
   form.KeyDown += ( object sender, KeyEventArgs e ) =>
   {
    if( e.KeyData == Keys.F5 )
     button.PerformClick();
   };
  }
 }`

Comment: You could also think about creating an interface: `public interface IRefreshable
 {
  void Refresh();
 }` and then use explicit interface implementation: `void IRefreshable.Refresh()
  {
   //do refreshing
  }`

Comment: thanks kai. i am not that expert in c#. how can i call this in the form. pls elaborate. thanks in advance.

Comment: @kai. got it. kai. thanks alot. u solved a big problem. can u please narrate me, how can i implement it through interface...

Comment: Via explicit interface implementation it is possible to create a method which is accessible from other classes but does not appear in the list of public methods (even if it is in fact like public). But you said above this is not your goal, so just skip it. And maybe you can rephrase your question to remove if from [on hold]. Or at least upvote the comment which helped you.

Comment: hi kai, still another problem facing. in form, i have 3 buttons, refresh, save and delete. so, i assigned F5 to refresh, F10 to save and F4 to delete. to implement this scenario, how to modify your code?. at the moment, only 1 button can be send na..i tried sending as 3 button parameters, but its recursively working. pls advise..

Comment: Actually when i click "save" button using F10, first time its fine, second time, it attempts 2 times, 3rd time 3 times and so on. so how to reinitialise it after each performclick.

Comment: Sounds like you invoked `HookRefreshButton()` from click event handler instead of constructor or `OnLoad()`. Please improve your original question to remove it from [on hold]

Comment: @kai. Thanks alot. i tried to improve my question. pls have a look. while, pls guide me, if the same can be achieved via interfaces.

Comment: You got me wrong about interfaces. I mentioned them because i misunderstood your problem before you further explained it. Of course it would be possible to involve interfaces but the whole thing is too complex for a comment. If above solution works for, just go with it.